# Scala/Spark determine the path of external table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-shell

I am having one external table on  on gs bucket and to do some compaction logic, I want to determine the full path on which the table is created.

```
val tableName="stock_ticks_cow_part"
val primaryKey="key"
val versionPartition="version"
val datePartition="dt"
val datePartitionCol=new org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName(datePartition)

import spark.implicits._

val compactionTable = spark.table(tableName).withColumnRenamed(versionPartition, "compaction_version").withColumnRenamed(datePartition, "date_key")
compactionTable. <code for determining the path>
```

Let me know if anyone knows how to determine the table path in scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`.inputFiles`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#inputFiles()) to

> Returns a best-effort snapshot of the files that compose this Dataset

Be aware that this returns an `Array[String]`, so you should loop through it to get all information you're looking for.

So actually just call

```
compactionTable.inputFiles
```

and look at each element of the Array

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct answer:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.TableIdentifier
lazy val tblMetadata = catalog.getTableMetadata(new TableIdentifier(tableName,Some(schema)))

lazy val s3location: String = tblMetadata.location.getPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DESCRIBE FORMATTED` SQL command and collect the path back to the driver.

In Scala:

```
val location = spark.sql("DESCRIBE FORMATTED table_name").filter("col_name = 'Location'").select("data_type").head().getString(0)
```

The same in Python:

```
location = spark.sql("DESCRIBE FORMATTED table_name").filter("col_name = 'Location'").select("data_type").head()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL commands `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` or `DESCRIBE FORMATTED <tablename>`. Both should return the `location` of the external table, but they need some logic to extract this path...

See also [How to get the value of the location for a Hive table using a Spark object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54060596/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-location-for-a-hive-table-using-a-spark-object)