# Show create table for internal tables with location in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive, azure-databricks

While executing `show create table` in hive, we have location url in the statement for both internal and external table. But when executing the same statement through spark (pyspark) we are only having location if the table is external. Is there any settings to have this location for internal table as well?

I want to collect the create statements with location for all tables from onprem to databricks. Databricks also displays create statements without location for internal tables.

We can get from location from desc table. But I would like to know if there is tweak to have it in `show create table`.

Example
Hive:

```
show create table db1.table1
```

In pyspark:

```py
createStatement = spark.sql("show create table db1.table1")

createStatement.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a related answer for [scala spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54060596/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-location-for-a-hive-table-using-a-spark-object).

The idea would be the same for you.  You could query the (likley derby) database that is used to hold the information for all spark tables.(Spark Metastore).

You also should know that by default databases/tables that are internal follow this [format](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/05/hive-a-data-warehouse-in-hadoop-framework/): (database is the name of the database and tablename the name of the table.

```
hdfs:/hive/warehouse/directory/[database].db/[tablename]
```

Comment: Thanks Matt for responding. I agree that the path can be derived either through concatenation of warehouse directory + database + tablename or through describe formatted command. But I am collecting DDLs for 5000+ tables under same database into a hive table. I will be using spark script to execute this DDL in Azure as External tables. If the location is available in the create statement, I could be easier to manipulate. Hence I was looking for any configuration which could help me with it.

Comment: I would suggest working with the spark metastore then to pull the information that you need.  This is what describe uses to generate the information.